# maven tomcat7:deploy fails with status code:403, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7, maven-3

I'm using a tomcat maven plugin to deploy my java web app. Now everythings work when i use tomcat 7.0.32, this is my plugin configuration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
       <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>my-tomcat</server>
                <path>/myapp</path>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

my settings.xml configuration

```
<servers>
   <server>
        <id>my-tomcat</id>
        <username>manager</username>
        <password>pwd</password>
   </server>
</servers>
```

my tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="managerGui" password="pwd" roles="manager-gui"/>

<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="manager" password="pwd" roles="manager-script"/>
```

while if use a different version of tomcat, for example 7.0.50, i get the following error

> code:403, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden

I also try to connect on tomcat 7.0.50 at

```
 http://localhost:8080/manager/text
```

and not work, while with the 7.0.32 version i get the authentication pop-up.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is 7.0.50 even working on your machine? Does http://localhost:8080 even work? Make sure that you installed the manager add-on.

Comment: As @hofan41 said, double check the [Tomcat 7.0.50 How To](http://chinkapin.pti.indiana.edu:9994/docs/manager-howto.html) about setting up the "manager app".

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue, solved it by creating settings.xml in C:\Users{userName}\.m2\ with following content
`<settings>
    <servers>
      <server>
        <id>my-tomcat</id>
        <username>manager</username>
        <password>pwd</password>
      </server>
    </servers>
</settings>`

It seems for some reason plugin not picking up credentials from %MAVEN_HOME%/conf/settings.xml and expect it to present in C:\Users{userName}.m2\settings.xml